# Why Basic HTML gets loaded

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

When I browse internet,basic HTML gets loaded on my computer. For eg.- for orkut or facebook login,only the text box appears,and when inputs are provided,and redirection is done,it says "error on page". Even on google search,basic HTML gets loaded on my computer.. I tried installing new Internet version i.e., IE8,but had the same problem. 
Kildly provide a good solution to this problem.

Comment: Any more details on that "error on page"? Often you can simply press Ctrl-C to copy the full error message. And it sounds like JavaScript *is* enabled, but do you know how to verify that? Did you try another browser?

Comment: Easy Solution: http://www.mozilla-europe.org/en/firefox/ Long Solution: What Windows are you using?

Comment: @bobby: presumably windows-xp, as that's what the question's tagged with.

Comment: @quack quixote: Ops, how the hack did I miss that tag? oO'

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas.

If a custom style sheet or other accessibility options are enabled, it might make websites appear very basic. (Even if you installed a new version of Internet Explorer, it is probably using the same settings as the old version.) Go to Tools, Internet Options, General tab, Accessibility button, and make sure everything is unchecked.

If JavaScript is disabled, or other security or privacy (cookie) settings are set too high you might get error messages on websites.

Go to Tools, Internet Options, Security tab, and click the "Reset all zones to default level" button. Look at the list of restricted sites to make sure you aren't blocking a site you need. Look at the list of trusted sites to make sure you aren't allowing too much access to a site you don't trust.

Go to Tools, Internet Options, Privacy tab, and click the Default button.

If you are still having problems, you can go to Tools, Internet Options, Advanced tab, and click the Reset button to reset all Internet Explorer settings to their default states.

If that still doesn't work, then you might need to start scanning for malware.

Answer (score 0):

Trey to reinstal your browser, I meen completly remove your current browser(settings, files, folders, registry entries) and reinstall it, you can install another type of browser to see if the problem persist, but don't let him import settings from your curent browser.

If you juse reinstall or update your current browser but don't completly remove it before, there can be setting that still stay on your PC and the new broser could use these settings and have the same behavior as the old one.

Comment: Don't try this. Attempting to remove IE is a bad idea.

Comment: @BlueNovember: IE can't be removed anyway.

Comment: which is why attempting to do so would be Bad :P

Answer (score 0):

Sounds liek you could have some malware interfering with your browsing.  Google for some malware scanners and check your system, or best option is to reinstall everything from scratch.

Comment: I would suggest you start with the AVG boot CD http://www.avg.com/us-en/avg-rescue-cd and scan your system.